# Ошибка компилятора CS1061

Tags: c#, компилятор

У меня во время сборки UWP пакетов на C# в Visual Studio 2017 возникает ошибка 
Ошибка  CS1061  "MainPage" не содержит определения для "ToFar", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "ToFar", принимающий тип "MainPage" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).
До этого я успешно создал пакеты приложения. Сейчас я сделал обновление и хочу собрать новые пакеты, но эта ошибка не дает этого сделать. В новом обновлении я заменил RadioButton с названием ToFar на ComboBox. При обычном запуске без создания пакетов ошибки не выскакивает. Что мне делать?

Comment: Запустите поиск по проекту на "ToFar" где-то у вас остались объявления этого имени.

Comment: Я уже искал, не найдено